# How to pass data from ViewControllers and show them into tableviewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, tableview

I want to pass data from my ViewController to TableViewCell, How can I do that. How to pass data from one ViewController and show them in TableViewCell.

Comment: Please read [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift):Create a Table View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)

Comment: use prepare for segue or delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit too vague, but I will try. If you are using a segue from another viewController and the data is, for example, an array of Strings i.e in your first viewController:

```
  var arrayOfStrings = ["StringRow1", "StringRow2"] // etc
```

and you want to be able to access this array when you enter a new viewController and use it for your `tableView` then you can use `prepareForSegue`

First, in your `viewController` with the `tableView` have a variable ready for the array:

```
  var arrayOfStrings = [String]()
```

Then you can pass the data over like this:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "SegueToTableView" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? YourTableViewController 
     {
            vc.arrayOfStrings = self.arrayOfStrings
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you arrive in your tableView viewController, your arrayOfStrings data will be passed.

This is a basic simple example as you did not provide much context.

Answer (score 0):

Creat variable in your cell class and in cell for row just assign that value to variable and use in your cell class.